# Process Encrypted S3 File in EMR (MapReduce)

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-s3, mapreduce, emr

I have a simple MapReduce job that I execute in EMR. The input file is encrypted with AES key and stored in S3.

How do I configure my MapReduce job to decrypt the S3 file before passing it to the mapper?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke AmazonS3EncryptionClient instead of AmazonS3Client

Comment: In MapReduce? I just add input locations to the job configuration. How do I select what client to use or pass the AES key to the job?

Comment: Have you created IAM role for the job you are trying to run?[refer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles.html)
`RunJobFlowRequest runFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest().withServiceRole("someRole").withJobFlowRole("someJobFlow")`

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured at the EMR-cluster level. For example, if you use client-side encryption on S3, you can specify the kms key id [in the emrfs-site.xml file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-emrfs-encryption.html). AWS Console and awscli also have corresponding support.